# org.json.JSONException: Value Connection of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, mysql, json, android-studio

I am writing a login function for my application and I suddenly started getting this error: `org.json.JSONException: Value Connection of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject` I don't recall modifying the code here at all and it used to work before. It suddenly stopped working when I started using the debug mode on android studio.

Here is a snippet of my code, the error seems to be on the 2 lines marked with /*ERROR*/:

`private String loginUrl = "http://10.0.2.2/user/login.php";`

```
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, loginUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() /*ERROR*/ {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response); /*ERROR*/
                        if (jsonObject.names().get(0).equals("success")) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonObject.getString("success"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            email.setText("");
                            password.setText("");
                            Log.d("test", "Going to Main.class");
                            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main.class));
                            //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonObject.getString("error"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    parameters.put("email", email.getText().toString());
                    parameters.put("password", password.getText().toString());
                    return parameters;
                }
            };
            requestQueue.add(request);
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is the value of `response`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like that the `response` object is not properly formatted to be converted into JSON object. [Example](http://json.org/example.html).

Comment: Yup I must have done something while showing someone the php file.

Answer (score 0):

[org.json.JSONObject(String json)](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject(java.lang.String)) Creates a new `JSONObject` with name/value mappings from the JSON string.

This exception means that your `response` parameter does not contain a valid JSON